# Making Global NSUinteger - objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I make the following NSUinteger an instance var so I can access it throughout my entire class?

```
NSUInteger indexArr[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

Comment: Just create a property and you can use it entire class.

Comment: It cannot be initialized this way even as a property, I dont think.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only real way to do this type of initialization in Objective C is to put your NSUinteger indexArr[4] in the interface description of your object, then in your init routine, initialize it with a loop!

Example:

In your object header file myObject.h

```
@interface myObject{
    NSUInteger indexArr[4];
}

@end
```

In your myObject.m file

```
@implementation myObject

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];

    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        indexArr[i] = i;

    return self;
}

@end
```